# How to get data from two temporary tables and insert in third table without adding new row in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to make a report where i need to get data from Two different tables. i cant use Join. So i am trying to insert in a temporary table. But it is returning more than one row for each insert. I want it in a single row.Below is the query in MS Sql Server.

```
     @month int= 0,
       @year int = 0, --(2020)
       @regionid int = null, --(13/14/16/17/18/19/20)
       @countryid int = null,
       @clientid int = null
AS
BEGIN
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempClientReport') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #tempClientReport
Create Table #tempClientReport
(
Client_ID                                       int,
Client_Name                                     varchar(250),
Project_Received_Request          int default 0,
Project_Delivered_Request         int default 0,
BAU_Received_Request              int default 0,
BAU_Delivered_Request                    int default 0
)


insert into #tempClientReport(Client_ID, Client_Name, Project_Received_Request, BAU_Received_Request,Project_Delivered_Request,BAU_Delivered_Request)
       select 
       RELEASE_MANAGEMENT_TRAN.CLIENT_ID, 
       Client_Name,
       Sum(case when REQUEST_ID = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as ProjectCount,
       Sum(case when REQUEST_ID = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as BAUCount,null,null
from   
       FLOW_TRANSACTION INNER JOIN RELEASE_MANAGEMENT_TRAN on RELEASE_MANAGEMENT_TRAN.RM_ID = FLOW_TRANSACTION.RM_ID 
inner join CLIENT_MASTER
       on RELEASE_MANAGEMENT_TRAN.CLIENT_ID = CLIENT_MASTER.CLIENT_ID
where 
(@month = 0 or (DATEPART(month,RELEASE_MANAGEMENT_TRAN.CREATION_DATE) = @month))
and (DATEPART(year,RELEASE_MANAGEMENT_TRAN.CREATION_DATE) = @year)
and (@regionid is null or RELEASE_MANAGEMENT_TRAN.REGION_ID = @regionid)
and (@countryid is null or RELEASE_MANAGEMENT_TRAN.GE_ID = @countryid)
and (@clientid is null or RELEASE_MANAGEMENT_TRAN.CLIENT_ID = @clientid)
and TO_STAGEID = '11'  and STATUS != 'R' 
--and CLIENT_MASTER.ACTIVE_STATE = 'A'
group by 
       RELEASE_MANAGEMENT_TRAN.CLIENT_ID,
       Client_Name


union all

select 
       RELEASE_MANAGEMENT_TRAN.CLIENT_ID, 
       Client_Name,null,null,
       Sum(case when REQUEST_ID = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as ProjectCount,
       Sum(case when REQUEST_ID = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as BAUCount
from   
       PACKAGE_QA INNER JOIN RELEASE_MANAGEMENT_TRAN on RELEASE_MANAGEMENT_TRAN.RM_ID = PACKAGE_QA.RM_ID 
inner join CLIENT_MASTER
       on RELEASE_MANAGEMENT_TRAN.CLIENT_ID = CLIENT_MASTER.CLIENT_ID
       where 
(@month = 0 or (DATEPART(month,RELEASE_MANAGEMENT_TRAN.CREATION_DATE) = @month))
and (DATEPART(year,RELEASE_MANAGEMENT_TRAN.CREATION_DATE) = @year)
and (@regionid is null or RELEASE_MANAGEMENT_TRAN.REGION_ID = @regionid)
and (@countryid is null or RELEASE_MANAGEMENT_TRAN.GE_ID = @countryid)
and (@clientid is null or RELEASE_MANAGEMENT_TRAN.CLIENT_ID = @clientid)
and STATUS    = 'C'
group by 
       RELEASE_MANAGEMENT_TRAN.CLIENT_ID,
       Client_Name
order by Client_Name
END

select * from #tempClientReport order by Client_Name

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempRegion') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #tempRegion
```

it gives result as below

```
1  Media    0       NULL   2    NULL
1  Media    NULL    0      NULL 2
3  Horizon  0       NULL   1    NULL
```

Media etc is the client name
I want that for each client it should give only in one row the data as you can see it gives two rows here.Please help

Comment: *"i cant use Join"* Why not? Also, your query above *has* a `JOIN`.

Comment: Side note, the above is a catch-all query, or "kitchen sink" query. At a minimum you should be added `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the query, to avoid bad query caching.

Comment: If your query orders by Client_Name, how does the resultset wind up with Media before Horizon?

Comment: @SMor these are dummy names.. i changed the names for confidentiality...

Answer (score 0):

Could you use SUM and GROUP BY like this:

```
select 
    Client_ID, [Client_Name],                                   
    SUM([Project_Received_Request]) AS [Project_Received_Request],
    SUM([Project_Delivered_Request]) AS [Project_Delivered_Request],
    SUM([BAU_Received_Request]) AS [BAU_Received_Request],
    SUM([BAU_Delivered_Request]) AS  [BAU_Delivered_Request]
from #tempClientReport
group by Client_ID, [Client_Name]
order by [Client_Name]
```

Comment: There is NO reason - NONE - to use the nolock hint here. And there is generally NO reason to [splatter the nolock hint](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) in code.

Comment: Thanks will try..but why do i have to use NO Lock here

Comment: I tried what you said. Still it is giving multiple row for Clients.

Comment: Do i have to remove sum from case statements and instead give it like u said

Comment: Sorry i checked. It is working. Thanks .. issue was duplicate client ids which i removed.